# htaccess get content from subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, nested, directory

I have searched a lot but cannot find the information i want. I have a domain `http://mydomain.com`, my html files are nested in 3 level subfolders (for example `thingy.html` is nested in `t/h/i/` folder, `testy.html` nested in `/t/e/s/` folder

Now i want to type `http://mydomain.com/testy.html` or `http://mydomain.com/thingy.html` in the browser, it should show the content of those files without being redirected to `http://mydomain.com/t/h/i/thingy.html` and `http://mydomain.com/t/e/s/testy.html`

Is this doable?

Could anyone please help me? I'm new to .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there's some kind of deterministic whay these 3 level subfolders are named, you'll have to do each one explicitly and separately. For example, the the htaccess file in your document root, you can have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?thingy.html$ /t/h/i/thingy.html [L]
RewriteRule ^/?testy.html$ /t/e/s/testy.html [L]
```

etc.